# Matrix of Random Number using polar rejection

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a matrix of Random numbers using Polar Rejection method with the code below. I don't see any error but the console does not show any results. My code is below:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program.GenerateRandom(); 
        }
         public static void GenerateRandom()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Please enter newtrials.");
             int newTrials=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
             Console.WriteLine("Please enter Steps.");
             int newSteps = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
               int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            double[,] v = new double[newTrials,newSteps];
            double[,] d = new double[newTrials, newSteps];
            double[,] l = new double[newTrials, newSteps];
            double[,] Z = new double[newTrials, newSteps];
            for (i = 0; i < newTrials; ++j)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < newSteps; ++i)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            Random rnd = new Random();
                            v[i, j] = 2 * rnd.NextDouble() - 1;
                            d[i, j] = 2 * rnd.NextDouble() - 1; ;
                            l[i, j] = Math.Pow(v[i, j], 2) + Math.Pow(d[i, j], 2);
                        }
                        while (l[i, j] >= 1.0);
                    }
                    Z[i, j] = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(l[i, j]) / l[i, j]) * v[i, j];

                }

            Console.WriteLine("values are:{0},{1}",Z[0,0],Z[0,1]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never increase j in your code. Reverse ++i, ++j in your for loops, ie use ++i in your first loop and ++j in your second loop.

Comment: As a side note, if you instantiate `Random` inside your loops you are going to get a lot of repeating numbers as `Random` seeds based on system time. You should move the instantiation outside the loops.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that are I believe are errors in this code:

1. `for (i = 0; i < newTrials; ++j)` and `for (j = 0; j < newSteps; ++i)`. You're incrementing the counter for the j loop in i and the counter for i loop in j. This is causing a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" when I run your code because the j loop isn't getting incremented in the j loop and thus the loop isn't stopping.
2. `Z[i, j] = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(l[i, j]) / l[i, j]) * v[i, j];` at this point in the program's execution the loops have reached the bounds of the arrays you declared above. So if the user input 10 and 10 this code is calling `Z[10, 10]`. Since arrays are zero based Z only has upper bounds of `Z[9,9]` this is throwing a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" as well.

The other consequence of the 2nd issue is that you're only writing an answer to the last index of the second dimension of the Z array. Meaning, if we use our 10 and 10 example again, results will only be written to Z[0, 9], Z[1, 9], Z[2, 9], Z[3, 9], Z[4, 9], Z[5, 9], Z[6, 9], Z[7, 9], Z[8, 9], and Z[9, 9]. I'm not sure what you're intending to do with this code but I think you have some logic errors.

I think you want something like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter newtrials.");
int newTrials = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please enter Steps.");
int newSteps = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
double[,] v = new double[newTrials, newSteps];
double[,] d = new double[newTrials, newSteps];
double[,] l = new double[newTrials, newSteps];
double[,] Z = new double[newTrials, newSteps];
Random rnd = new Random();
for (i = 0; i < newTrials; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < newSteps; j++)
    {
        do
        {
            v[i, j] = 2.0 * rnd.NextDouble() - 1.0;
            d[i, j] = 2.0 * rnd.NextDouble() - 1.0;
            l[i, j] = Math.Pow(v[i, j], 2.0) + Math.Pow(d[i, j], 2.0);
        }
        while (l[i, j] >= 1.0);
        Z[i, j] = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(l[i, j]) / l[i, j]) * v[i, j];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < newTrials; i++)
{
    Console.Write("[");
    for (j = 0; j < newSteps; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", Z[i, j]);
    }
    Console.Write("]\n");
}            
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I am trying to simulate a matrix of random numbers, say 10 by 4 where 10 is newTrials and 4 is newSteps. For a given index of newTrials; i.e. 'j' I need 4 random numbers. This should continue for 10 trials. Therefor, Z should be a 10 by 4 matrix of random numbers. Could you please suggest any solution? I am very tired of trying for two days.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed the i and j. However, now my Z matrix is outside of the bounds of Array.

Comment: Please see my updated comment with the updated code. I believe that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dex. The last Console.WriteLine thing was for a testing that the program in fact was working. I wanted the entire matrix but I thought a test should suffice. Your correction of taking the braces before Z[i,j] was the key. Could you suggest how to save the Matrix Z once simulated? Thanks again.

Comment: I think that you're saving the matrix correctly. If you're looking for a true Matrix, with all the mathematical bells and whistles, you could always look into using the Math.Net Matrix class.